# Google spreadsheet key version

Tags: java, google-sheets-api, google-drive-api

On March 2014, Google spreadsheet upgraded to Google sheets.

With Google Spreadsheet API v3 (java):

- on sheet created on old version, the function `gsService."oldsheet".getKey()` return a 23 length key.
- on sheet created on new version, the function `gsService."newsheet".getKey()` return a 44 length key.

My problem is the following.. I would like to use Drive API to retrieve a file using key previously requested from Google Spreadsheet API.

So, with Drive API:

```
driveService.files.get(sheetKey);
```

This works fine with the newest version of a Google spreadsheet file (post-March 2014) but returns a "not found" result on an older version of a Google spreadsheet file (pre-March 2014).

How can I convert old key to new key [on server side]?

Answer (score 0):

Spreadsheet key that works with drive:

I had a problem that sounds the same as this. I switch to using a key created with google apps script.

```
function getSpreadsheetURLKey() {
  var spreadsheetId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
  var spreadsheetDriveFile = DriveApp.getFileById(spreadsheetId);
  var spreadsheetURLKey = spreadsheetDriveFile.getId();
  return spreadsheetURLKey;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Unfortunately, I have to convert the old spreadsheet key on server side.

Comment: I suspect DriveApp.getFileById(spreadsheetId); is using the google drive api. So you may be able to do it server side. But if not, it is possible to make calls to google apps script from a server and get a result back.